# Reset SELECT list not working in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, selectlist

I use the following code to reset the selected index of a select list in IE:

```
$("#list")[0].selectedIndex = -1
```

However, that doesnt appear to work in FF and Chrome. Can anyone tell me what the correct way to achieve this would be?

Comment: does your select list have a blank option with a value of `-1`? If not, your solution would be to add it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the `.prop` method of jQuery. Documentation can be found [here](http://api.jquery.com/prop/).

Get:

```
$("#list").prop("selectedIndex");
```

Set:

```
$("#list").prop("selectedIndex",-1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not this?

```
$("#list option").attr("selected", false);
```